# Не поздно ли создавать дочернюю тему после подключения и настройки плагинов

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте! Начинаю знакомство с WordPress, узнала, что желательно создавать дочерние темы, чтобы не было глюков при обновлении родительской темы, но уже много изменений успела внести на сайте (напрямую файлы никакие не редактировала, но плагины настраивала и подключала). Стоит ли мне заново скачать родительскую тему и внести все правки уже в дочернюю? (немного жалко времени, но не хочется проблем в будущем). Или плагины и настройки темы (только через админку) никаких проблем не вызовут? Дело в том, что у меня поначалу слетела немного верстка в дочерней теме, потыкала в настройках языков - все стало на место (подключен плагин polylang). И вообще, когда говорят о создании дочерних тем, имеется в виду их создание сразу после установки родительской или в принципе это можно делать при уже настроенном сайте, при условии, что еще не редактировались файлы напрямую?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не редактировались файлы родительской темы, то дочернюю можно создавать без проблем. Все настройки родительской темы сохранятся. Изменение файлов плагинов не оказывает влияния на темы.

Comment: А если редактировались? Если родительская работает, дочерняя тоже будет работать

Comment: Вопрос не в том, будет ли работать, а "стоит ли мне заново скачать родительскую тему и внести все правки уже в дочернюю?" И ответ - "Если не редактировались файлы родительской темы, то дочернюю можно создавать без проблем". Т.е., если файлы редактировались, то создать можно, но правки родительской надо перенести вручную в дочернюю, иначе при обновлении они слетят.

Comment: Правки родительской темы в любом случае слетят при обновлении родительской темы. Все правки вам стоит делать в дочерней. Дочернюю тему можно создавать в любое время, она будет учитывать только актуальное состояние родительской темы. Водпрес при отрисовке страниц сначала обращается к родительской теме, потом к дочерней, потом рисует страницу

Comment: Мне можете это не объяснять, я автору поста отвечал. И, кстати, вы глубоко не правы, насчёт порядка загрузки тем. Сначала загружаются файлы дочерней темы. Это позволяет перекрывать функции основной темы в дочерней (если, конечно, эти функции в родительской теме обернуты в `if ( ! function_exists() ) { }` )

Comment: сначала загружаются действительно файл стилей дочерней темы, как активная тема, но он обращается к родительской

Comment: Не так. Файл стилей дочерней темы полностью перекрывает файл стилей родительской. Поэтому там ставят @import или, что лучше, делают в functions.php wp_enqueue_style() родительской. А вот сам файл functions.php дочерней темы загружается раньше functions.php родительской, что позволяет перекрывать функции. Почитайте об этом у kama, например.

Answer (score 0):

Тема обычно состоит из файлов: шаблоны страниц, style.css, functions.php и тд. Создавая новую тему вы обычно создаете новую директорию с названием темы, а в ней файл style.css, в котором явно указываете от какой темы наследуете. При наследовании вы получаете функционал файлов родительской темы (стили, шаблоны, функции) с возможностью его переопределения (перезаписи на свой лад). Это значит что вы получаете функционал родительской темы, который можете изменять под себя в дочерней теме. Если при обновлении родительской темы функционал темы меняется, функционал дочерней темы тоже МЕНЯЕТСЯ! Контент, создаваемый в админке хранится в базе данных, а не в файлах темы. Это значит, что если вы обновите родительскую тему, создадите новую дочернюю тему или измените существующую дочернюю тему, контент постарается отобразиться как и до изменений в тех же постах, страницах и виджетах, чтобы были до изменений темы. Я советую вам прочитать оф документацию. https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B А так же экспериментируйте в тестовом окружении (можно на локалке) с темами, с шаблонами, с functions.php не боясь что-то сломать. Только так вы поймёте жизненный цикл сайта вордпресс, его функции-хуки и откроете для себя много нового и интересного в этой чудесной CMS.